# Render PayPage Error - Even after url encoding

Tags: testing

Good Morning (morning in Oregon).  I am going through the Intuit Developer Testing process and continue to get errors when attempting to render the PayPage with ticket and opid strings that were provided to me in the previous step.  To prevent links in this message, I separated the https:// from the remainder of the url.

Using:
Firefox browser (internet explorer for intuit is under construction?)
Windows XP Professional version 2002 service pack 3

---

**ORIGINAL DATA FROM PREVIOUS STEP AND VARIABLE URL FOR RENDER PAYPAGE STEP:**

Ticket=JiRr77+9RA7vv73vv70JdVcrYWnvv71b77+977+977+9Cu+/vW7vv70a13061215442877+9DhprATIXA++/ve+/vXfvv73vv73vv73doO+/vXDvv70nHWTvv73v

OpId=77-977-9VO--vX130612154428Dvv73vv70ZHyo7

PTC url with variables:  (https://) paymentservices.ptcfe.intuit.com/checkout/terminal?Ticket=(X)&OpId=(Y)&action=checkout

---

**When I DO NOT encode the url**, I get the Secure Payment Processing window with the following message:  Transaction Not Processed - Our system is currently facing some intermittent problems. Please try again in few minutes.

> Unencoded url used:
>
> > (https://) paymentservices.ptcfe.intuit.com/checkout/terminal?Ticket=JiRr77+9RA7vv73vv70JdVcrYWnvv71b77+977+977+9Cu+/vW7vv70a13061215442877+9DhprATIXA++/ve+/vXfvv73vv73vv73doO+/vXDvv70nHWTvv73v&OpId=77-977-9VO--vX130612154428Dvv73vv70ZHyo7&action=checkout

**When I encode the ticket portion of the url only** and then paste the results into the url, I get the Transaction not processed screen again.

> Resulting url w/ encoding of ticket only:
>
> > (https://) paymentservices.ptcfe.intuit.com/checkout/terminal?Ticket=JiRr77%2B9RA7vv73vv70JdVcrYWnvv71b77%2B977%2B977%2B9Cu%2B%2FvW7vv70a13061215442877%2B9DhprATIXA%2B%2B%2Fve%2B%2FvXfvv73vv73vv73doO%2B%2FvXDvv70nHWTvv73v&OpId=77-977-9VO--vX130612154428Dvv73vv70ZHyo7&action=checkout

When I encode the entire original url I get the QBMS Error Page and [Intuit Logo] - Not Found - Error Code 404

> Encoded url entire resulting url encoded:
>
> > (https://) paymentservices.ptcfe.intuit.com/checkout/terminal%3FTicket%3DJiRr77%2B9RA7vv73vv70JdVcrYWnvv71b77%2B977%2B977%2B9Cu%2B%2FvW7vv70a13061215442877%2B9DhprATIXA%2B%2B%2Fve%2B%2FvXfvv73vv73vv73doO%2B%2FvXDvv70nHWTvv73v%26OpId%3D77-977-9VO--vX130612154428Dvv73vv70ZHyo7%26action%3Dcheckout

I feel I have tried everything and I do not know what else to try.  I am under a deadline to get this done.  I tried everything suggested in the one thread I found where this issue was discussed.  But I noted there was never really an answer on that [thread](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=50&threadid=16911&highlight_key=y&keyword1=paypage).  I hope you can help me out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, and found the cause. They want the value for Ticket and OpId url encoded. In most scripting languages like PHP, that will turn spaces into "+" symbols. They then expect those plus symbols to also be url encoded. So, in PHP if you do something like this to the Ticket and OpId and any other parameters you pass it will fix the problem (this assumes $ticket and $op_id are already set):

$ticket = str_replace('+','%2B',urlencode($ticket));
$op_id = str_replace('+','%2B',urlencode($op_id));